# Yield in callback generator not activated

Tags: ecmascript-6

Please consider the following ES6 function. My intention is to fetch the direction data from google maps. The google map function is taking origin, destination, travelMode and callback as parameters.

```js
// Get direction data from Google API. Individual exports for testing
export function* fetchDirections() {
  const mapApiGoogle = yield select(selectMapApiGoogle());
  const google = mapApiGoogle.library;
  const origin = yield select(selectOrigin());
  const destination = yield select(selectDestination());
  new google.maps.DirectionsService().route({
    origin: new google.maps.LatLng(origin.lat, origin.lng),
    destination: new google.maps.LatLng(destination.lat, destination.lng),
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    }, function* (result, status) {
      if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        yield put(MapDirectionsRequestedGoogleSuccess(result));
      } else {
        yield put(MapDirectionsRequestedGoogleError(result));
      }
    }
  );
}
```

The problem is, when the DirectionService().route() function is executed and callback with result called, my fetchDirections() generator does not recognize the yield in the callback. How should i amend the code above to be able to utilize yield in the callback function?

**UPDATE:** Normally, i use the generator in redux-saga. For testing purpose, i invoke the generator as below. I just realized, that the callback generator does not get instantiated, so the inner yield will never be reached. Do you have any idea how to control the inner callback generator from the fetchDirections() or how to test the result?

```js
describe('fetchDirections', () => {
  let fetchSaga = false;
  const googleStub = {
    maps: {
      LatLng: function (lat, lng) {
        return { lat, lng }
      },
      TravelMode: {
        DRIVING: 'DRIVING'
      },
      DirectionsStatus: {
        OK: 'OK'
      }
    }
  };
  beforeEach(() => {
    fetchSaga = fetchDirections();
    const selectDescriptor = fetchSaga.next().value;
    expect(selectDescriptor).toEqual(select(selectMapApiGoogle()));
  });
  it('should invoke directions api', () => {
    googleStub.maps.DirectionsService = () => {
      return {
        route: function(origin, destination, travelMode, callback) {
          callback('directions','OK');
        }
      }
    };
    const putDescriptor = fetchSaga.next({ library: googleStub }).value;
    expect(putDescriptor).toEqual(put(MapDirectionsRequestedGoogleSuccess('directions')));
  });
});
```

Comment: How are you invoking your generator? Can you please show the code where you're using it?

Comment: For reference, i added the UPDATE section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The function* declaration (function keyword followed by an asterisk) defines a generator function, which returns a Generator object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*

First you should instantiate Generator function and get back generator object from it. So I think callback won't for work here as you expect, it will stop after initialization.

Comment: it is a good point, in this case, the callback generator will not get instantiated. How am i supposed to control callback triggered by external library from the generator?

Comment: I will have to probably transform the callback function to Promise. Implementation in progress.

Comment: Yep, promisify this part `new google.maps.DirectionsService().route({...})`
Then you'll be able to get resolved value as a generator and work with it as usual. It should be handled outside of `* fetchDirections()`.